# Memory exception while using OpenCV (2.4.5)

Tags: opencv

This is my program. It's really easy. I'm trying to run an iteration 10,000 times but after the 838th iteration I always get this message:

> OpenCV error: Insufficient memory < Failed to allocate 2457620 bytes > in unknown function.

Why does this memory exception get thrown?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h" 
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for(int i = 0;i<100000;i++)
    {
        CvMat *mat = cvCreateMat(640*480,5,CV_64FC1);
        CvMat *mat_ = cvCreateMat(640*480,1,CV_64FC1);

        cvGetCol(mat,mat_,1);
        printf("%d th iteration \n",i);

        cvReleaseMat(&mat_);
        cvReleaseMat(&mat);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you have a memory leak. The line:

```
CvMat *mat_ = cvCreateMat(640*480,1,CV_64FC1);
```

allocates memory for a `CvMat` with the specified dimensions. When you pass that pointer to `cvGetCol()`, the pointer is changed to point to the specified column in `mat`. However, the memory you previously allocated *is never freed*, resulting in a memory leak.

To fix this, change the line:

```
CvMat *mat_ = cvCreateMat(640*480,1,CV_64FC1);
```

to the following:

```
CvMat temp;
CvMat* mat_ = &temp;
```

This should fix your memory leak. However, if at all possible, I **strongly** recommend you use the C++ API (using `cv::Mat`) instead. The C API is deprecated, and the C++ API is easier to use and offers automatic memory management.